# Belgium work visa stamping in the USA for an Indian H-1B holder?

Tags: working-visas, indian-citizens, h1-visa, belgium

I am an Indian citizen working in the USA on an H-1B visa for the last 5 years. I have a valid I-797 but the stamping on the passport has expired.

I have applied for a job in Belgium and I'm in the process of getting an offer. Can I get the work visa stamped for Belgium in the USA, without going back to India?

Are there any different options available?

Answer (score 1):

The Belgian diplomatic mission to the US says that [after you receive your work permit from your employer](http://unitedstates.diplomatie.belgium.be/en/visa-belgium/employees)

> You can then contact the appropriate consular office in whose jurisdiction you are a resident, to apply for a long term visa.

Since you reside in the United States, you should apply in the United States.  If you try to apply in India, your application may be rejected because you do not reside there.

The "appropriate consular office" can be found by visiting the [list of missions in the US](http://unitedstates.diplomatie.belgium.be/en/embassy-and-consulates).  Visit the *Jurisdiction* page for each mission, and see whether your place of residence is listed.  If it is, that is the mission where you must apply.

Comment: so does that mean,  even though i am an Indian citizen i can apply in USA through Belgian Embassy?

Comment: @chetank it means that you *must* apply in USA.  Furthermore, you must apply at the Belgian embassy or consulate in whose consular jurisdiction your place of residence lies.  So, for example, if you live in Colorado, you must apply through the Los Angeles consulate general, not the embassy.